# Extract element from function result in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm trying to get the value from the element(?) named 'price' in this block of code into another script to use as the amount to charge on a custom Stripe Checkout page.

```
function CalculatedRecommendedDistance() {

CalculateDistanceforAllAlternativeRoutes();

var origin = document.getElementById('pick_up_address').value;
var destination = document.getElementById('drop_off_address').value;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

  service.getDistanceMatrix({

    origins: [origin],
    destinations: [destination],
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false,
    avoidFerries: false

  }, function(response, status) {
    var originList = response.originAddresses;
    var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputRecommended');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

    //Display distance recommended value
    for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {

        outputDiv.innerHTML += originList[i] + ' to ' + destinationList[j] +
          ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in ' +
          results[j].duration.text + '<br>';

//Convert driving distance to price

          document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = booking_fee + base_fare + (rate_per_km * parseFloat(results[j].distance.text));

// The value that this statement produces is what I need ==> parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").innerHTML);

      }
    }
  });
}
```

Or more specifically, the value that this statement produces:

```
parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").innerHTML);
```

I've tried putting the following, and many variations besides, in the same script to create a variable, but the result returned in the console is always either NaN or undefined.

```
var solution = document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = booking_fee + base_fare + (rate_per_km * parseFloat(results[j].distance.text));
```

Here's the full script:

```
<script>

var booking_fee = 0.50;
var base_fare = 1.50;
var rate_per_km = 1.30;
var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
var text = '3.14someRandomStuff';

var placeSearch, originautocomplete;
var componentForm = {
street_number: 'short_name',
route: 'long_name',
locality: 'long_name',
administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
country: 'long_name',
postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {

// Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
// location types.

originautocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(

/** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */

(document.getElementById('pick_up_address')), {
types: ['geocode']
});

// Set initial restrict to the greater list of countries.

originautocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({
'country': ['nz']
});

destinationautocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
(document.getElementById('drop_off_address')), {
types: ['geocode']
});

destinationautocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({
'country': ['nz']
});
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.

function geolocate() {

if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
var geolocation = {
lat: position.coords.latitude,
lng: position.coords.longitude
};
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
center: geolocation,
radius: position.coords.accuracy
});
autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
});
}
}


function CalculatedRecommendedDistance() {

CalculateDistanceforAllAlternativeRoutes();

var origin = document.getElementById('pick_up_address').value;

var destination = document.getElementById('drop_off_address').value;

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

  service.getDistanceMatrix({

    origins: [origin],

    destinations: [destination],

    travelMode: 'DRIVING',

    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,

    avoidHighways: false,

    avoidTolls: false,

    avoidFerries: false

  }, function(response, status) {
    var originList = response.originAddresses;
    var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputRecommended');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = '';


    //Display distance recommended value

    for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {

      var results = response.rows[i].elements;

      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {

        outputDiv.innerHTML += originList[i] + ' to ' + destinationList[j] +
          ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in ' +
          results[j].duration.text + '<br>';

//Convert driving distance to price

          document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = booking_fee + base_fare + (rate_per_km * parseFloat(results[j].distance.text));

// The value that this statement produces is what I need ==> parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").innerHTML);

      }
    }
  });
}

function CalculateDistanceforAllAlternativeRoutes() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var start = document.getElementById('pick_up_address').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('drop_off_address').value;
  var method = 'DRIVING';
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode[method],
    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    optimizeWaypoints: true
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    var routes = response.routes;
    var distances = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {

      var distance = 0;
      for (j = 0; j < routes[i].legs.length; j++) {
        distance = parseInt(routes[i].legs[j].distance.value) + parseInt(distance);
        //for each 'leg'(route between two waypoints) we get the distance and add it to 
      }
      //Convert into kilometer
      distances.push(distance / 1000);
    }
      var maxDistance = distances.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    });
    //Display distance having highest value.

    outputDiv.innerHTML = Math.round(maxDistance[routes.length - 1]) + " KM";
    });

}

</script>
```

Many thanks for any help you're able to provide.

Comment: Looking at [the examples for the `Distance Matrix` responses](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_responses), the `results[j].distance.text` used in your expression is a human-readable `string` (`1173 mi`, for example) hence the `NaN` result. Instead, using `results[j].distance.value` (seems to be in meters) should solve this.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. Unfortunately, even after changing ```results[j].distance.text``` to ```results[j].distance.value``` I've not been able to access that value. I get the message "Can't find variable" in response to any attempt to see the value of results, results[j], j, results[j].distance.value, results[j].distance.text.

Comment: I can see the contents of the object, price, but I haven't been able to turn this into a number variable. To do that, I tried ```var ab = Number(parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").innerHTML));```

Comment: Even though ```isNAN(Number(parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").innerHTML)))``` returns false and ```typeof ab```  returns number, when I look up the variable ab in the web browser console after running the script, it says NaN.

Comment: Basically, I'm having difficulty turning the object, price, into a number variable, or otherwise getting a number out of the distance calculations somehow that I can use as a variable, amount, to send to Stripe Checkout.